# Selection of bones to selection of tails of bones

Tags: python, armature, bones

I have an armature with a bunch of bones with zero length, and I can select one and do `Select > Similar > Length` to get all of the bones with no length, however I'm unable to scale bones since they have no length, or increase the length since the whole bone is selected.

I would like to be able to just select only tails of bones, or select a bunch of bones then change the selection so it only affects the tail.

Answer (score 0):

I did actually figure this out, I'm just making this post in case other people need it. I select the bones i want the tail of and run this python script.

```py
import bpy

bselect = bpy.context.selected_bones
bpy.ops.armature.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for bone in bselect:
    bone.select_tail = True
```

I could have done `bone.select = False` and `bone.select_head = False` however it just didnt work to deselct the head. so not sure.